# Apache NiFi RouteText, configured as 'route to matched...' but marked as invalid ("must be dynamic properties to match against")

Tags: apache-nifi, bigdata

I'm trying to use the RouteText processor (in Apache NiFi) to extract the contents of a CSV file to convert to JSON; I have the RouteText processor configured properly (I believe) with "route to matched if line matches all conditions", and I've attached the "matched" relationship to the downstream processor.  But the processor won't run: it's marked as "Dynamic properties is invalid because in order to route text there must be dynamic properties to match against".

As far as I can tell from the doc (https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteText/) I don't need to specify a dynamic property because I'm using the built-in "matched" relationship (as per: "Routes data that matches the value specified in the Dynamic Property Value to the Relationship specified in the Dynamic Property Key.").

I must be misunderstanding that part of the doc.  Can anybody correct me?

Answer (score 4):

The RouteText processor always requires dynamic properties to specify the patterns to match against.

When "Route to matched if line matches all conditions" then it uses the values of those properties to get the patterns and if a line matches all of them then it routes to matched.

When "Route to each matching property name" is selected, it uses the values of the dynamic properties as patterns to match against, but this time if a line matches one of those values, it uses the dynamic property name as the name of a relationship to route to.

So if you add a dynamic property like "foo" = "AAA.*" and select "Route to matched if line matches all conditions", all lines starting with "AAA" will go to matched. If you selected "Route to each matching property name" all lines starting with "AAA" will go to "foo". In either case there needed to be a dynamic property to match against.

Comment: Ok thanks: I misinterpreted the usage (esp. re. grouping regular expression).  But it's not obvious to me how to make use of "foo" in the next processor (AttributesToJSON, in this case): in this case I'm trying to parse pipe-delimited csv data, so I've (now) created dynamic property foo as a regex to pull out all the elements (which works, and matches all elements as expected): but then in the destination processor (AttributesToJSON) I've left Attribute List empty, but I'm only seeing one row come through, and it only has foo.0 and foo.1 populated.  CSV parsing seems hard in NiFi!

Comment: Is the goal to create a JSON document for each line of a CSV? The original question was about RouteText, but what you described in the last comment sounds more like ExtractText.

Comment: The goal is to parse a CSV document and save it as JSON.  I tried ExtractText but had some issues, and in my (minimal) research I gathered ExtractText is not recommended for this use case, and one should use RouteText instead.  I did get this to work via Avro BTW, but I wanted to try to make it work without the intermediate Avro conversion (but without writing my own processor), as an exercise.

Comment: Ok, the most efficient approach would be a custom processor that streams in the CSV and streams out a new JSON document, thus not having to produce a lot of intermediate flow files. Using only out-of-the-box processors you could do what you already did with ConvertCSVToAvro and ConvertAvroToJson, or SplitText with line count of 1 to get each line into a flow file, ExtractText to parse the line and get the values into attributes, AttributesToJson, then MergeContent to merge all of the individual JSON documents back together.

Comment: There is an example template that shows how to convert a CSV to JSON using ExtractText and ReplaceText: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/57904847/CsvToJSON.xml?version=1&modificationDate=1442927496000&api=v2  This was created before AttributesToJson existed so you could use AttributesToJson instead of ReplaceText in this example.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm surprised that csv parsing isn't already addressed by a dedicated processor, but perhaps I have a biased view of how data comes in!  I guess I'll just use the csv->avro->json flow for now and not worry too much about the overhead from the intermediate avro stage (indeed I may need avro quite soon anyway!).

Comment: @BryanBende In my project, we are discouraged to use Custom Processors. But, custom processors actually bring down the complexity by a fair amount. Kindly share if there are any drawbacks from using Custom processors. Really appreciate all your input for the Nifi Community. Thanks !!

Comment: @Tammy you are definitely right that in a lot of cases you can build custom processors specific to your use-case that can simplify things, there is no drawback to using custom processors, although the provided processors have been through more review and testing just because they have been used by more people